# Javascript error: .split is not a function

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to separate a full name into first and last name and populate the corresponding fields. However, I keep running into a JavaScript error ".split is not a function"

This is my code

```
function SplitName (executionContext) {​​​

var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();    
var FirstName = formContext.getAttribute('firstname');
var LastName = formContext.getAttribute('lastname');
var FullNameField = FullName.getValue();

if (FullNameField =! null){​​​

var SplitField = FullNameField.split(" ",2);
var FirstNameValue = SplitField[0];
var LastNameValue = SplitField[1];
        FirstName.setValue(FirstNameValue);
        LastName.setValue(LastNameValue);
    }​​​

else {​​​
        FirstName.setValue('');
        LastName.setValue('');
    }​​​
}​​​
```

Any help/suggestion on what am I doing wrong would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where do you define `FullName`?

Answer (score 2):

`FullNameField =! null`

You're assigning FullNameField to "true" with this. Switch it to:

`FullNameField != null`

Comment: You got me too excited lol. Changed it, same error :(

Comment: Well, that was still an error you had, which would produce the same issue. :D

What's the content of `FullNameField` when you console log it just before the split?

Comment: Good to know, was always under the impression js wasn't that strict with syntax. THank you

Answer (score 0):

the variable "FullNameField" should be a string before you run "split" method on it.

Hence, try using

```
FullNameField.toString().split(" ",2);
```

Answer (score 0):

So somehow this made it work.

```
function SplitName (executionContext) {​​​

var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();    
var FirstName = formContext.getAttribute('firstname');
var LastName = formContext.getAttribute('lastname');
var FullNameField = FullName.getValue();

if (Lastname != null){

if (FullNameField != null){​​​

var SplitField = FullNameField.split(" ",2);
var FirstNameValue = SplitField[0];
var LastNameValue = SplitField[1];
        FirstName.setValue(FirstNameValue);
        LastName.setValue(LastNameValue);
    }​​​

else {​​​
        FirstName.setValue('');
        LastName.setValue('');
    }​​​
}
}​​​
```